# flutter doctor issue because file is not existing

Tags: flutter, flutter-doctor

i am getting this message every time i run flutter doctor (flutter has exited unexpectedly: "FileSystemException: Exists failed, path = ''C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start' (OS Error: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect. , errno = 123)".) what can i do ?

every time i try to run my project or flutter doctor -v i get this message and nothing to do ,
i tried to delete and re download flutter but it was the same :(

and this was the flutter_14.txt file content :-

Flutter crash report.
Please report a bug at https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues.

### command

flutter doctor --android-licenses

### exception

FileSystemException: FileSystemException: Exists failed, path = ''C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start' (OS Error: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
, errno = 123)

```
#0      _Directory.existsSync (dart:io/directory_impl.dart:92:7)
#1      ForwardingFileSystemEntity.existsSync (package:file/src/forwarding/forwarding_file_system_entity.dart:43:33)
#2      ErrorHandlingDirectory.existsSync.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/error_handling_io.dart:492:22)
#3      _runSync (package:flutter_tools/src/base/error_handling_io.dart:590:14)
#4      ErrorHandlingDirectory.existsSync (package:flutter_tools/src/base/error_handling_io.dart:491:12)
#5      AndroidStudio.latestValid (package:flutter_tools/src/android/android_studio.dart:244:64)
#6      AppContext._generateIfNecessary.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:104:42)
#7      _LinkedHashMapMixin.putIfAbsent (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:535:23)
#8      AppContext._generateIfNecessary (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:92:20)
#9      AppContext.get (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:121:32)
#10     AppContext.get (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:119:24)
#11     AppContext.get (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:119:24)
#12     androidStudio (package:flutter_tools/src/globals.dart:65:45)
#13     runInContext.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/context_runner.dart:104:32)
#14     AppContext._generateIfNecessary.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:104:42)
#15     _LinkedHashMapMixin.putIfAbsent (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:535:23)
#16     AppContext._generateIfNecessary (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:92:20)
#17     AppContext.get (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:121:32)
#18     AppContext.get (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:119:24)
#19     AppContext.get (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:119:24)
#20     androidLicenseValidator (package:flutter_tools/src/android/android_workflow.dart:30:65)
#21     DoctorCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/doctor.dart:53:32)
#22     FlutterCommand.verifyThenRunCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1568:12)
<asynchronous suspension>
#23     FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1336:27)
<asynchronous suspension>
#24     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
<asynchronous suspension>
#25     CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:212:13)
<asynchronous suspension>
#26     FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:296:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
#27     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
<asynchronous suspension>
#28     FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:244:5)
<asynchronous suspension>
#29     run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:91:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
#30     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
<asynchronous suspension>
#31     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:91:3)
<asynchronous suspension>
```

### flutter doctor

```
encountered exception: FileSystemException: Exists failed, path = ''C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start' (OS Error: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
, errno = 123)

#0      _Directory.existsSync (dart:io/directory_impl.dart:92:7)
#1      ForwardingFileSystemEntity.existsSync (package:file/src/forwarding/forwarding_file_system_entity.dart:43:33)
#2      ErrorHandlingDirectory.existsSync.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/error_handling_io.dart:492:22)
#3      _runSync (package:flutter_tools/src/base/error_handling_io.dart:590:14)
#4      ErrorHandlingDirectory.existsSync (package:flutter_tools/src/base/error_handling_io.dart:491:12)
#5      AndroidStudio.latestValid (package:flutter_tools/src/android/android_studio.dart:244:64)
#6      AppContext._generateIfNecessary.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:104:42)
#7      _LinkedHashMapMixin.putIfAbsent (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:535:23)
#8      AppContext._generateIfNecessary (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:92:20)
#9      AppContext.get (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:121:32)
#10     androidStudio (package:flutter_tools/src/globals.dart:65:45)
#11     runInContext.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/context_runner.dart:113:32)
#12     AppContext._generateIfNecessary.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:104:42)
#13     _LinkedHashMapMixin.putIfAbsent (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:535:23)
#14     AppContext._generateIfNecessary (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:92:20)
#15     AppContext.get (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:121:32)
#16     androidValidator (package:flutter_tools/src/android/android_workflow.dart:29:51)
#17     _DefaultDoctorValidatorsProvider.validators (package:flutter_tools/src/doctor.dart:139:44)
#18     Doctor.validators (package:flutter_tools/src/doctor.dart:230:47)
#19     Doctor.startValidatorTasks (package:flutter_tools/src/doctor.dart:236:45)
#20     DoctorText._validatorTasks (package:flutter_tools/src/doctor.dart:734:60)
#21     DoctorText._validatorTasks (package:flutter_tools/src/doctor.dart)
#22     DoctorText._runDiagnosis (package:flutter_tools/src/doctor.dart:738:53)
#23     DoctorText.text (package:flutter_tools/src/doctor.dart:730:36)
#24     DoctorText.text (package:flutter_tools/src/doctor.dart)
#25     _createLocalCrashReport (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:233:51)
#26     _handleToolError (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:195:31)
<asynchronous suspension>
#27     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
<asynchronous suspension>
#28     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:91:3)
<asynchronous suspension>
```